# How to use MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

I'm having trouble understanding MOSFET.
There is always a voltage at the drain pin (my case: MOSFET on 5 V, MOSFET off 4.8 V).
I've tried n-channel irfz44n and p-channel irf4905, but the result is still the same.
How to get the drain pin to 0 V in the off condition?[image: fet]

Comment: Have you tried to simulate it?

Comment: IRFZ44 requires more than 5V on the gate to turn on. You need a logic level MOSFET that will turn on with less than 5V.

Comment: @winny yes, i simulate on proteus, schematic work.  But when i make pcb led still light up.

Comment: Component flipped so that you are conducting though body diode?

Comment: `How to get the drain pin to 0 V in the off condition?` - that just won't happen.

Comment: @winny.  OK, I'll check again.
don't know why it always fails when using mosfet.
usually I use transistors and relays for large currents.

Comment: @andy aka.  Why?  with that scheme the led can't turn off.
what is the solution, what should be changed?

Comment: Because when the N channel MOSFET is off it is open circuit and does not force anything to 0 volts.

Comment: In any event, Q7 should have a resistance across its base and emitter to ensure Q7 is biased off when the switch is open. I would use 100K across the base resistor/switch junction and the Q7 emitter. Try it.